# JSP says a class is abstract that doesn't appear to be

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, wsdl

I have a web service TaskListWS written in Java and am using NetBeans 8.0.2

I have created the wsdl and tested it via the Test Web Service feature.

I then did a "Generate and Copy WSDL" to my client sc_demo.

The JSP files now all have errors saying that the

```
com.shoulderscorp.services.TaskListWS service = new com.shoulderscorp.services.TaskListWS();
com.shoulderscorp.services.TaskListWS port = service.getTaskListWSPort();
```

is in error because TaskListWS is abstract and can't be instantiated.  The class is not abstract and there are not abstract methods in the class.

Here is the method being called:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "TaskListWS")
public class TaskListWS {

    private boolean inited = false;

    private QueueManager qm = new QueueManager();

    private static final String[] statusValues = {"Active", "Completed", "Waiting", "Damaged"};

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getTaskListForUser")
    public String getTaskListForUser(@WebParam(name = "userToken") String userToken) {
...
}
```

The wsdl file has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is Metro/2.3 (tags/2.3-7528; 2013-04-29T19:34:10+0000) JAXWS-RI/2.2.8 JAXWS/2.2 svn-revision#unknown. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/" name="TaskListWS" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:tns="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/" schemaLocation="TaskListWS_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="toString">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:toString"/>
  </message>
  <message name="toStringResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:toStringResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="deleteQueueEntry">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteQueueEntry"/>
  </message>
  <message name="deleteQueueEntryResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:deleteQueueEntryResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getTaskListForUser">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getTaskListForUser"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getTaskListForUserResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getTaskListForUserResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getAllQueueEntriesWithStatus">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllQueueEntriesWithStatus"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getAllQueueEntriesWithStatusResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllQueueEntriesWithStatusResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateWaitingEntriesService">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateWaitingEntriesService"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateWaitingEntriesServiceResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateWaitingEntriesServiceResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getAllQueueEntries">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllQueueEntries"/>
  </message>
  <message name="getAllQueueEntriesResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getAllQueueEntriesResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateEntry">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateEntry"/>
  </message>
  <message name="updateEntryResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:updateEntryResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="queueEntry">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:queueEntry"/>
  </message>
  <message name="queueEntryResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:queueEntryResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="TaskListWS">
    <operation name="toString">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/toStringRequest" message="tns:toString"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/toStringResponse" message="tns:toStringResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="deleteQueueEntry">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/deleteQueueEntryRequest" message="tns:deleteQueueEntry"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/deleteQueueEntryResponse" message="tns:deleteQueueEntryResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getTaskListForUser">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/getTaskListForUserRequest" message="tns:getTaskListForUser"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/getTaskListForUserResponse" message="tns:getTaskListForUserResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllQueueEntriesWithStatus">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/getAllQueueEntriesWithStatusRequest" message="tns:getAllQueueEntriesWithStatus"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/getAllQueueEntriesWithStatusResponse" message="tns:getAllQueueEntriesWithStatusResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateWaitingEntriesService">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/updateWaitingEntriesServiceRequest" message="tns:updateWaitingEntriesService"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/updateWaitingEntriesServiceResponse" message="tns:updateWaitingEntriesServiceResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllQueueEntries">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/getAllQueueEntriesRequest" message="tns:getAllQueueEntries"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/getAllQueueEntriesResponse" message="tns:getAllQueueEntriesResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateEntry">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/updateEntryRequest" message="tns:updateEntry"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/updateEntryResponse" message="tns:updateEntryResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="queueEntry">
      <input wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/queueEntryRequest" message="tns:queueEntry"/>
      <output wsam:Action="http://services.shoulderscorp.com/TaskListWS/queueEntryResponse" message="tns:queueEntryResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="TaskListWSPortBinding" type="tns:TaskListWS">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="toString">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="deleteQueueEntry">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getTaskListForUser">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllQueueEntriesWithStatus">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateWaitingEntriesService">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getAllQueueEntries">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateEntry">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="queueEntry">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="TaskListWS">
    <port name="TaskListWSPort" binding="tns:TaskListWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

I'm not sure why this is occurring or how to fix it.

Comment: `com.shoulderscorp.services.TaskListWS service = new com.shoulderscorp.services.TaskListWS();
com.shoulderscorp.services.TaskListWS port = service.getTaskListWSPort();` which of these is throwing the error?

Comment: instantiation on first line, says it is an abstract class.  Second line says cannot find symbol getTaskListWSPort says cannot find symbol in service